# Convert Unix path with slashes to Windows path

Tags: c++, windows, qt, unix

I am trying to run a command to open a specific location in the `explorer.exe` and select a specific file:

```
QUrl url = QUrl::fromUserInput(file.absoluteFilePath());
QString str = "explorer.exe /select,\"" + url.toString() + "\"";
system(str.toStdString().c_str());
```

This works great with Windows locations.

But since I open as well locations from a NAS and MAC user can create folders there I have a problem with folders like this:

> //NAS/**FOLDER/With/BackSLASH**/file.ext

Since it's possible on a Mac to use slashes for file/folder naming it cannot be recognized by the `system()` funciton and `QString` converts it to `U+002F`.

In Windows explorer it is shown as:

> **FOLDER•With•BackSLASH**

and, if I use the command prompt to navigate into such a folder it shows the folder name as following:

> **PRODUCER'S NOTES 86**

Does anyone have an idea how to handle this special case or how to convert this path to a path which can be passed as argument for the `explorer.exe`?

**/* EDIT 08/31/2018*/**

I changed my Code to:

```
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
void exportManager::BrowseToFile(QString filename)
{
TCHAR tchar[512];
USES_CONVERSION;
_tcscpy(tchar, A2T(filename.toStdString().c_str()));

ITEMIDLIST *pidl = ILCreateFromPath(tchar);
 if (pidl) {
    SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidl, 0, 0, 0);
    ILFree(pidl);
 }
}
....
QString path = qFile.absoluteFilePath();
BrowseToFile(path.replace('/', '\\'));
```

But this still doesn't solve the Problem with the Backslashes and Slashes in Folder/FileNames.
Seems the conversion "filename.toStdString().c_str()" causes the Problem.

If i print (qDebug()) the path it looks like this: 
//NAS/Folder\uF022With\uF022BackSLASH/file.ext

I found this Question and this Solved my problem.
[QDesktopServices::openUrl with selecting specified file in explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137692/qdesktopservicesopenurl-with-selecting-specified-file-in-explorer)

Comment: Pretty sure you need to use double backslash, as single backslash is considered a byte. 

Try 

\\NAS\\FOLDER\\With\\BackSLASH\\file.ext

Comment: @MichaelStrobel that only applies to **string literals** at compile-time, not to user-provided data at runtime.

Comment: @Jonas you really should be using the [`SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shopenfolderandselectitems) function instead of using `system()` to invoke `explorer.exe` via a command line.  If you can navigate to the target folder in Explorer, you can also programmably obtain PIDLs to the folder and its files for use with the function.

Comment: Question (maybe not directly relevant; just curious): Why are you not using `QProcess` instead of `system()`? You won't have to call `toStdString().c_str()` as it accepts a `QString`. As you are in Qt realm, you ought to make use of most of its facilities.

Comment: Yeah i obviously didn't read the question too well. >.<

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @remy i updated the code but still have the issue, i think its because of toStdString().c_str() this.

Comment: @azeem i tried QProcess but there was the same issue with the unix backslashes, so i tried the system call.

Comment: @JonasSorgenfrei well, for starters, `\uF022` represents a **private use** Unicode codepoint, it is not a real character. So that is the first thing you need to deal with. Second, you shouldn't be converting the `QString` to `std::string` at all, let alone to a `TCHAR[]` buffer. Converting a `QString` with non-ASCII characters in it to `std::string` will loss data. Use `ILCreateFromPathW()` instead, then you can use the `QString`'s Unicode data as-is, passing either `(WCHAR*)filename.data()` or `filename.toStdWString().c_str()` to `ILCreateFromPathW()`, thus ensuring there is no data loss.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-platform way of constructing an FS path with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3194725/608639) and [Qt equivalent of PathAppend?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13014145/608639). Also reference `QDir::separator`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function called `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems()`to invoke the `explorer.exe` via command line.
This is a sample code to do so:

```
void BrowseToFile(LPCTSTR filename)
{
    ITEMIDLIST *pidl = ILCreateFromPath(filename);
    if(pidl) {
        SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidl,0,0,0);
        ILFree(pidl);
    }
}
```

Hope this help; cheers

Comment: Hello @HasanPatel, i tried to use the code with the function call: BrowseToFile((LPCTSTR)"C:\\Windows\\CSUP.txt");  But it didn't work ... Can you tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: Okay got it, the Cast was Wrong. I corrected it:                                                          TCHAR tchar[512];
USES_CONVERSION;
_tcscpy(tchar, A2T(stdStr.c_str()));

Answer (score 0):

Qt is multi platform framework so you should take advantage of it as much as it is possible.

There is nice API which will do everything for you without such complications: [QDesktopServices::openUrl](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl).

---

edit:
Based on comment [there is already a solution on SO for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3546503/1387438).

Comment: Hello Marek, thanks for your responds. I tried using openUrl but it opens the file itself and not the selected file inside of an explorer window.

Comment: ok so you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3546503/1387438